# Static method error

Tags: java

I am confused as to why I have a non static method error. It says  "non-static method getGrade(double) cannot be referenced from a static context getGrade(myGPA);" I have been reading on what non static method. I get it I can't call something that doesn't exist. Since you haven't created an object, the non-static method doesn't exist yet. A static method (by definition) always exists. So this is my code below, and the error says "non-static method getGrade(double) cannot be referenced from a static context getGrade(myGPA);" 
I created an object of that, but gave me a "cannot find symbol error." I know it is something minor, can someone please guide me as to what I can do? THANK YOU in advance!

The program is supposed to take the user's input (GPA, in decimal format, and covert that into percentile, and response to the user.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

  public class GradeCalc {
 public double myGPA;
 public double numGrade;

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your GPA.");
    double myGPA= myScanner.nextDouble();

    getGrade(myGPA);
    System.out.println(myGPA);
    }

    public double getGrade(double myGPA) {
    if(myGPA==0.0 || myGPA==0.8 || myGPA==0.9 || myGPA==1.0 || myGPA==1.1 ||           
      ||myGPA==1.8 || myGPA==1.9 || myGPA==2.0 || myGPA==2.1 || myGPA==2.2 || myGPA==2.3        || myGPA==2.4 || myGPA==2.5 || myGPA==2.6 || myGPA==2.7 || myGPA==2.8 || myGPA==2.9 || myGPA==3.0 || myGPA==3.1 || myGPA==3.2 || myGPA==3.3 || myGPA==3.4 || myGPA==3.5 || myGPA==3.6 || myGPA==3.7 || myGPA==3.8 || myGPA==3.9 || myGPA==4.0 ) {
        double numGrade = (myGPA*10+55);
    }
        if (myGPA == numGrade)
            System.out.println(numGrade);
    else  {
        System.out.println("Try again.");
    }
     return numGrade;
}
}
```

Comment: No offense, but that `if` is _so_ ugly. Not to mention it breaks when I enter 1.15. Why didn't you just write `if(myGPA <= 4.0)`?

Answer (score 2):

Non-static method cannot be call from a static context.

You can create an instance of GradeCalc class, and use this instance to call the non-static method.

Like,

```
GradeCalc gradeCalc = new GradeCalc();
gradeCalc.getGrade(myGPA);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call a non-static method from a static one (`main`), which is non possible  because your `GradeCalc` object is not defined ; either you can declared `getGrade` as a static method (but you can't use attributes), or create a `GradeCalc` object inside your `main` and call the method with it.

Best would be to separate `main` method and `GradeCalc` class, by creating a class reserved to `main` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public double getGrade(double myGPA)
```

To

```
public static double getGrade(double myGPA)
```

Comment: And remove the two declarations of `public double myGPA;` and 
`public double numGrade;` at the top.

Comment: Or even better: create an instance of the object and use `getGrade` from that object instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradeCalc {
    public double myGPA;
    public double numGrade;
    Scanner myScanner;

    private void readGPA() {
        myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your GPA.");
        myGPA = myScanner.nextDouble();
        myScanner.close();
    }

    public void computeGrade() {
        if (myGPA == 0.0 || myGPA == 0.8 || myGPA == 0.9 || myGPA == 1.0
                || myGPA == 1.1 || myGPA == 1.8 || myGPA == 1.9 || myGPA == 2.0
                || myGPA == 2.1 || myGPA == 2.2 || myGPA == 2.3 || myGPA == 2.4
                || myGPA == 2.5 || myGPA == 2.6 || myGPA == 2.7 || myGPA == 2.8
                || myGPA == 2.9 || myGPA == 3.0 || myGPA == 3.1 || myGPA == 3.2
                || myGPA == 3.3 || myGPA == 3.4 || myGPA == 3.5 || myGPA == 3.6
                || myGPA == 3.7 || myGPA == 3.8 || myGPA == 3.9 || myGPA == 4.0) {
            numGrade = (myGPA * 10 + 55);
        }
    }

    public void showResult() {
        if (myGPA == numGrade) {
            System.out.println(numGrade);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Try again.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GradeCalc gradeCalc = new GradeCalc();
        gradeCalc.readGPA();
        gradeCalc.computeGrade();
        gradeCalc.showResult();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hint: the solution **is not** marking the other methods and fields as `static`. That's a **bad design** and OP won't learn the real meaning of `static` field/methods.